# Show that the dual space of the set of finite sequences of isomorphic to the set of all infinite sequences

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, vector-spaces

Given a field $\mathbb{F}$, let $V$ be the vector space of all finite sequences $(a_1,a_2,a_3,...)$ with entries $a_i \in \mathbb{F}$. Show that the dual space:

$V^*=\mathbb{L}(V,F)$

is isomorphic to the space $\mathbb{F}^\infty$ of all sequences.

Comment: By "*all finite sequences*" you mean all sequences having only finitely many non-zero entries, right?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Hint :** The sequences
$$(1,0,0,\dots ), (0,1,0,\dots),(0,0,1,0,\dots)\dots$$form a basis of $V$; every linear functional $f:V\to  \Bbb F$ is uniquely determined by its value on these sequences, which can be arranged as an infinite sequence
$$(f(1,0,0,\dots),f(0,1,0,\dots),\dots)$$
in $\Bbb F$. This gives you a bijection $V^*=\mathbb{L}(V,\Bbb F)\cong \Bbb F^\infty $, and you can check that it is linear, and thus an isomorphism.